# I cannot find a text field on screen using iOS UI test

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

I'm trying to create an automated UI test for my iOS application in Xcode, but I am running into the problem. Here's the scenario being tested:

This is an iOS storyboard application with two view controllers. The initial view controller displays a username text field, a password text field, and a sign-in button. When the sign-in button is tapped, if the user has two-factor authentication enabled, another view will be displayed by following the segue that displays it as a modal over the current view controller.

Here's my code:

```
// application: XCUIApplication
let username = application.textFields["Username"]
username.tap()
username.typeText("testuser")
let password = application.secureTextFields["Password"]
password.tap()
password.typeText("TWO-FACTOR-PASSWORD")
application.buttons["SignIn"].tap()
let authenticationCode = application.textFields["AuthenticationCode"]
authenticationCode.tap()
authenticationCode.typeText("12345")
```

The problem that I get is that `authenticationCode.exists` is always false even though I see it on screen.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see any code that says `authenticationCode.exists`, so how do you know it is `false`? Also, how do you know you "see it on the screen" - that is, how do you know that what you see on the screen is `authenticationCode`?

Comment: I have set a debugger breakpoint in the code and evaluated `authenticationCode.exists` and it comes back `false`. I have also in earlier iterations of the code put in the expectation (`expect(authenticationCode.exists).to(beTrue())` and it fails because the result is false. When I say I can see it on the screen, I'm watching the automation live in the simulator or on my phone. I can see that tapping the SignIn button executes the segue and I can see the text field visually on the screen, so I know that it is there. I have also enabled automation on the modal view and I can access that.

Comment: I'm going to suggest that this is not your dialog but is rather a system dialog (similar to the keyboard, or the password dialog when you make an App Store purchase). You'd be able to see it, because it is there, but you wouldn't be able to access it through Accessibility driven from your app's UI Test. Might that be the explanation?

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean by “this is not your dialog but is a system dialog”. I enabled accessibility in the view for my modal view controller and gave that an identifier, and I can access the view using application.otherElements[“MyAuthenticationView”]. I would assume that I wouldn’t be able to do that if your suggestion were correct? But I still can’t see the controls that are children of that view.

Comment: So this _is_ your view? It's some kind of alert that you are putting up? Then I would suggest that you're trying to access its elements incorrectly. How about using the Recording feature and seeing how the system encodes a tap in that text field?

Comment: No. It’s not an alert. It’s a UIViewController-backed view that is being presented modally using a segue in the storyboard. I did try using the recorder tool, but the code that it generates doesn’t work either. It seems to be unable to handle modal views. I was hoping that someone here had come across this and found a manual solution that works with modals.

Comment: Okay, but that's good info. Let me see if I can reproduce.

Comment: Nope, I can't reproduce. I'm putting up a presented view controller whose view is a small alert-like dialog, and my UI test is able to record tapping on that button and can then tap it. I have to suggest that you are doing something wrong that you're not telling us about. It would be nice if you could reduce the problem to an MCVE and post it.